# Glide.js — как узнать в какую сторону перешел слайд?

Tags: javascript, slider

Я использую слайдер glide.js
Как узнать в какую сторону перешел слайд: в право или налево? Мой кейс: есть два одинаковых слайдера. Мне надо, чтобы одинаковые слайды одновременно не показывались. Т.е. если при смене слайда у первого слайдера, этот слайд совпадает со слайдом из второго слайдера, то он автоматически прокручивает на еще +1 слайд (если свайпнул на право), либо -1 (если свайпнул на лево).

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать `glide.index`. Если они совпадают для обоих слайдеров, то производить манипуляции с принудительным перелистыванием.

Comment: Я так и делаю:
    if (glideCompareSliders[0].index === glideCompareSliders[1].index) {
        glideCompareSliders[0].index++;
    }

Но проблема в том, что в данном случае будет работать, только если свайп (или клик) был на правую сторону. А мне надо предусматривать и левую и делать что-то вроде glideCompareSliders[0].index--;

Comment: Если из методов, описанных в документации ничего годного нет для такой задачи, то можно хранить исходный индекс, и после события перелистывания сравнивать его с текущим. Если увеличился - значит листаем в одну сторону, если уменьшился - значит в другую. Но тут тоже свои трудности будут с переходом через 0-й индекс слайда, если слайдер зациклен. Костыль, конечно, но в теории реализуемо.